# Apply payments to charges recursively SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in a single table both charges and payments. Payments are "applied" to charges in order to balance the account to zero. There is no specific order to apply, as long as all charges are balanced to zero (or most of them).

After the SP I'm trying to build there would be two possible states of the table. As I said, I don't care how they are "applied" as long as most of charges' balances is zero.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Transactions (
TrxID       INT IDENTITY,
TrxType     BIT, -- 1 for Charges, 0 for Payments
TrxDescription  VARCHAR(MAX),
Amount  DECIMAL(13,2),
ApplyTo     INT -- TrxID of the charge to which the payment is "applied"
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(1,'Charge1',100,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(0,'Payment1',-80,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(0,'Payment2',-15,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(1,'Charge3',200,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(0,'Payment4',-20,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(0,'Payment5',-80,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Transactions VALUES(0,'Payment6',-105,NULL);

SELECT * FROM dbo.transactions

SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM dbo.Transactions;
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM dbo.Transactions WHERE TrxType=1;
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM dbo.Transactions WHERE TrxType=0;

-- CORRECT APPLICATION
UPDATE dbo.Transactions SET ApplyTo=1 WHERE TrxID IN(2,5)
UPDATE dbo.Transactions SET ApplyTo=4 WHERE TrxID IN(3,6,7)

-- The global balance is zero
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM dbo.Transactions

-- Both charges have zero balance
SELECT t.*,t.Amount+b.Balance 'Balance'
FROM dbo.Transactions t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount)Balance
         FROM dbo.Transactions t2
         WHERE t.TrxID=t2.ApplyTo
)b

-- WRONG APPLICATION
UPDATE dbo.Transactions SET ApplyTo=1 WHERE TrxID IN(2,3,5)
UPDATE dbo.Transactions SET ApplyTo=4 WHERE TrxID IN(6,7)

-- The global balance is zero
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM dbo.Transactions

-- Charges dont have correct balance, as they could be both zero if applied correctly
SELECT t.*,t.Amount+b.Balance 'Balance'
FROM dbo.Transactions t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount)Balance
         FROM dbo.Transactions t2
         WHERE t.TrxID=t2.ApplyTo
)b
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should be getting an error at the first insert statement for "Number of columns supplied is less than the number of columns in the table..."

Comment: The optimization of the charges applied is an odd requirement. In a normal accounting situation, Rows 2 and 3, and $5 from row 5, would be applied to the first charge. The remainder of row 5 + the rest would apply to the second charge. Otherwise you can end up in a situation where you can not evenly apply the payments. For example, if you had a total of 20 payments of $15 each, how would you apply them?

Comment: What you appear to be looking for is akin to a packing algorithm, which is a separate class of problems with somewhat complex theoretical issues. It is simplified in that it is only a one dimensional packing problem, though. You might want to look at [Gert-Jan's SQL Server Bin Packing solutions](https://gertjans.home.xs4all.nl/sql/binpacking/intro.html)

Comment: @Anand the first column is identity so it will get inserted automatically.

Comment: @Anand - I was surprised, but I tested the code and it works in SQL 2012. I must have missed that change.

Comment: @LaughingVergil you are right, but i will be doing this only for accounts which I previously know the global balance is zero and charges balance is zero too, meaning all charges could be applied correctly without splitting. I know this because is part of a migration project from one system to a new one and these premises are met.

Comment: Thanks guys @LaughingVergil and Ivan Alvarez; learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to solve is the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). This is an NP complete problem, and even the best algorithms run in exponential time O(2<sup>N/2</sup>).

Given that your problem looks like a balance sheet that could involve thousands of payments and charges (subsets and sums), there is not an exact solution that can run in a reasonable amount of time.

Here is a solution that will make a best effort to apply the payments using a MySQL stored procedure:

```
BEGIN


    DECLARE charge int;
    declare charge_id int;
    DECLARE payment int;
    declare payment_id int;
    declare foundrows int;

    balance_loop: LOOP

       SELECT trxid, amount into charge_id, charge 
        from transactions 
        where trxtype = 1
        and applyto is null
        limit 1;

        SET foundrows = (SELECT FOUND_ROWS());

        if foundrows = 0 then
            call debug(concat('Finished '));
            leave balance_loop;
        end if;

        call debug(concat('Balancing charge ', charge_id));  
        call debug(concat('starting with charge amount: ', charge));

        payment_loop: while charge > 0 do
            call debug(concat('start charge: ', charge));

            SELECT trxid, ABS(amount) into payment_id, payment
            FROM transactions
            WHERE trxtype =  0
            AND applyto is null
            AND ABS(amount) <= charge
            order by RAND()
            limit 1;


            call debug(concat('applying payment: ', payment));
            set charge = charge - payment;      

            call debug(concat('remaining charge: ', charge));


            if charge >= 0 then
                update transactions 
                set applyto = charge_id
                where trxid = payment_id;               
                call debug(concat('applied payment_id', payment_id, ' to charge ID ', charge_id));
            end if;     

        end while;

        update transactions set applyto = 0 where trxid = charge_id;

    end loop;

END
```